# How to extend Class with module in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to extend a class with logging module. Here is my code:

```
import logging

class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='mylogs.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

And I want to call something like this:

```
from core import Log

Log.info("Information Log")
Log.debug("Debug Log")
```

In English, I want to use all of the `logging` module functions with my `Log` class. How can I do it?

Comment: `class log(Logging): def __init__(self): super().__init__(self)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)